# counting days Idle when not being worked on

Tags: sql, gantt-chart, tableau-desktop, alteryx

I am currently working on a project that tracks parts going through different processes. My goal is to calculate how many days it is not in a process. in the picture it was simple enough when only one task is going on at a time. you first take the:

end date of the process - start date = # of days the process takes
The task end date - task start date = task duration

## of days the process - takes Sum together all task durations = how many days idle

but it is possible for multiple tasks to be going on at the same time. so i need to be able to figure that out and the equation above will not work because the total number of days would be over counted. this is built in Tableau using an SQL query. im open to any way of figuring this out through SQL, ALteryx and/or tableau

jsut thinking about it and asking IT

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with your expected result? This is a good reference for improving your question: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Reason being, the appropriate query will entirely depend on the exact structure of your data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.